# jq/fromdateiso8601 discrepancy on MacOS/Ubuntu

Tags: jq, iso8601

I run following two commands on both MacOS and Ubuntu :

```
jq -n '"1971-08-01T01:00:00Z" | fromdateiso8601'
jq -n '"1972-08-01T01:00:00Z" | fromdateiso8601'
```

On MacOS,   they give 49856400 and 81482400.

On Ubuntu, they give 49856400 and 81478800.

Why there is a difference of one hour for 1972, but no difference for 1971 ?

Both systems have jq-1.6.

*Update 1*

Windows behaves the same way as MacOS.

*Update 2*

The dates where difference happens are as follows :

```
1972-03-20 - 1972-10-29 (inclusive)
...
2022-03-28 - 2022-10-30
```

So it seems MacOS/Windows implementations apply one hour on DST dates from 1972 onwards, but not for the years 1969,1970, 1971.

Whereas Ubuntu implementation does not apply at all.

Comment: This is going to come down to differences between the operating systems' libc implementations (or the time zone databases they're distributed with) that aren't specific to jq at all. And... what do you really expect to get out of that as a useful takeaway?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would you explain that libc implementation on MacOS/Windows may add one hour for one date (1972) but not for the other (1971) ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Regarding `what do you really expect to get out of that as a useful takeaway`, it's more for understanding than for `usefulness`.

Comment: Have you tried finding out at what specific date it starts to differ? Or if later on they catch up and/or fall apart again? It could give a hint for the reason. A hypothesis based on the difference being exctaly 1 hour is that one OS may apply currently valid TZ affiliations or DST regulations (like based on month and day only), while the other one may use a historical DB to determine whether or not to apply them in a given year. On the other hand, with `Z` given it should be TZ/DST-independent UTC time… Anyway, I can confirm that for the dates given, Arch (unsuprisingly) behaves like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "master" version of jq fixes the issue (*). It's nice when jq and gojq agree:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Mac-mini.local 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0 ...

$ jqMaster -nM '"1971-08-01T01:00:00Z","1972-08-01T01:00:00Z" | fromdateiso8601'
49856400
81478800

$ gojq -n '"1971-08-01T01:00:00Z","1972-08-01T01:00:00Z" | fromdateiso8601'
49856400
81478800
```

——

(*)
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/3c5b1419a278dfb192666b33197dc182c670290d

Comment: So it is indeed an issue with jq. How can we download/use the "master" version of jq ?

Comment: One way: `brew install --HEAD jq`. Or visit the installation page at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation